# Are questions being moved to other stackExchange sites? Where is my old SuperUser question?

Tags: support

I came to SuperUser today to check an old question. The question have very good answers on it.

https://superuser.com/questions/5940/hidden-features-of-the-iphone

But it gives me a 404. I suspect that it was moved to other site, but can't find it using Google.

I would be great help if the 404 of a moved question can give the link of the new site hosting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now find all the useful answers from your Super User question copied on the electronic gadgets site, on the corresponding question:

[Undocumented iPhone features](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/252/undocumented-iphone-features).

*I only left out one sarcastic answer and one which was apparently wrong (downvoted 3 times).*

Comment: Nice work @Gnoupi!

Comment: Good golly, were you bored or something @Gnoupi ;p

Answer (score 1):

Nope it was deleted by @random

This is due to us moderators cleaning up Super User now that there are potentially new sites that cover these topics.

Furthermore, whether it was useful or not, it was off-topic and therefore correctly deleted.

Comment: ummm, to bad, the answers were very good with pictures and all.

Comment: @Eduardo - it's not definitive, we can undelete it for a while, if someone is motivated to add its content to the equivalent question on the gadget site: http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/252/undocumented-iphone-features

Comment: Ah well, I'll do it.

Comment: Been on a clean-deleting bender for the past couple of days. About 10 pages of done-for questions.